# No acciona botón en DialogFragment

Tags: android-studio, dialog-fragment

Hola buenas tardes tengo un problema como mi DialogFragment (FragmentProduct) en el cual declaro mis elementos e inicializo de mi layout (fragment_product.xml), tengo varios botones pero uno en específico el que tiene el id btnAgregar el cual puse un OnClickListener y dentro hago con Lg.d para saber si entra. Al presionar el botón no me imprime mi mensaje, pero tampoco me manda ningún error.

Espero que me puedan apoyar a saber porque no me está imprimiendo el mensaje.

Gracias.

> fragment_product.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FragmentProduct">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/activity_item_details"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="10"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="9.5"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/productimage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_cart_plus_solid"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtVCod"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Codigo"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/gen_black"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtVDesc"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="Producto"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/gen_black"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                        android:text="Cantidad: "
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/txtVMenos"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:backgroundTint="#eeeeee"
                        android:text="-"/>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/txtVMas"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:text=""/>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnAgregar"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:backgroundTint="#eeeeee"
                        android:text="+"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                </LinearLayout>


                <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/view_width_small"
                    android:background="@color/grey_light"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:elevation="30dp"
            android:background="@color/gen_black">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtVCancelar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text="CANCELAR"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textColor="@color/gen_white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/add_to_cart"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/gen_white"
                android:text="AGREGAR"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textColor="@color/gen_black"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

> FragmentProduct.java

```
package com.example.pegasso;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link FragmentProduct.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link FragmentProduct#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class FragmentProduct extends DialogFragment {

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    // Creo los elementos
    public TextView txtVMas, txtVCancelar;
    public Button btnAgregar;

    public FragmentProduct() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment FragmentProduct.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static FragmentProduct newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FragmentProduct fragment = new FragmentProduct();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product, null);
        txtVMas = view.findViewById(R.id.txtVMas);
        txtVCancelar = view.findViewById(R.id.txtVCancelar);
        btnAgregar = view.findViewById(R.id.btnAgregar);

        txtVCancelar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FragmentProduct.this.dismiss();
                Log.d("Holisssssss------","hhhhhhhhhh");
            }
        });



        btnAgregar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int cantidad = 1;

                if (cantidad < 500) {
                    cantidad++;
                    txtVMas.setText(Integer.toString(cantidad));
                    Log.d("Contador-----------------------", ""+cantidad);
                } else {
                }
            }
        });
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: txtVMas es un EditText no un boton.

Comment: Hola, perdon es el boton con el id btnAgregar le hice un OnClick pero no me imprime nada pero tampco marca error

Comment: Podría asegurar que funciona, pero me parece que el problema en este caso es el LogCat, cambia el filtro de "Verbose" a "Debug" y revisa nuevamente. @Javierfr

Comment: Listo ya lo cambie, corro la app y checo que imprima?

Comment: si, revisa nuevamente

Comment: El LogCat me sale en blanco, completamente en blanco, me fije en el Run pero no me imprime nada

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95037/discussion-between-elenasys-and-javier-fr).

Comment: Ya presione alt+6 pero aun no queda, no imprime cuando presiono el boton como si no lo presionara

Comment: Una solucion es que ponga en el botton la funcion onClick, eso te generara un metodo en el activity y desde el activity podras pulsar el boton

Comment: Otra cosa porque estas extendiendo de DialogFragment  y no Fragment, en el oncreate al inflar la vista tienes que pasar el container, en tu caso no se esta pasando ... haz de nuevo el fragement extendiendo de Fragement y veras como si te sale bien

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product, container,false);
    txtVMas = view.findViewById(R.id.txtVMas);
    txtVCancelar = view.findViewById(R.id.txtVCancelar);
    btnAgregar = view.findViewById(R.id.btnAgregar);

    txtVCancelar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FragmentProduct.this.dismiss();
            Log.d("LOG","Cancelar");
        }
    });



    btnAgregar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int cantidad = 1;

            if (cantidad < 500) {
                cantidad++;
                txtVMas.setText(Integer.toString(cantidad));
                Log.d("LOG", "Agregar : "+cantidad);
            } else {
            }
        }
    });
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view;
}
```

Aparte de eso, uno de los botonees lo tienes como un texview, revisa bien el codigo, pero con eso tendria que funcionar. un saludo y nos cuentas

Te pongo un ejemplo del xml y fragment completo

Fragment

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;


public Button btnAgregar,buttonQuitar;

public BlankFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment BlankFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static BlankFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container,false);

    btnAgregar = view.findViewById(R.id.btnAgregar);
    buttonQuitar = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonQuitar);

    buttonQuitar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Log.d("LOG------","Quitar");
        }
    });



    btnAgregar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int cantidad = 1;
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Toasd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("LOG", "Agregar");

        }
    });

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view;
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

}

xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".BlankFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/activity_item_details"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

   <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="quitar"
    android:id="@+id/buttonQuitar"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancelar"
        android:id="@+id/btnAgregar"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ya comentó que el botón es btnAgregar pero aún así no se muestra el mensaje en el LogCat.

Comment: si estoy diciendo que tiene que cambiar el en l onCreate devolver la vista.inflada en el ejemplo que tengo puesto funciona perfectamente